# How to publish test coverage to Github pull request using Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have following set up: Github Enterprise for source, Jenkins pipelines for CI. I use https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-organization-folder-plugin to build every pull request in Github. I can publish build result(passed or failed) back to Github. I want to publish test coverage results to Github pull request also, so that review will be able to see it. Before switching to pipelines I used https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin. Now it doesn't work.

Is there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my pull request was merged it is possible to use https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin with Jenkins pipelines. To do that one need to write

`currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
step([$class: 'CompareCoverageAction'])`

There is a check, that build status should be "SUCCESS", so you need to set the status to "SUCCESS" before calling the plugin, otherwise nothing will be triggered. Additional notes can be found on plugin's Github page.

Comment: does this still work for you? can you please take a look at https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-pr-coverage-status-plugin/issues/39